# Starting MariaDB at Boot (on macOS Catalina)

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mariadb

I have a Mac mini running macOS 10.15 (Catalina) and I have installed mariadb 10.5.9 via homebrew.

Everything runs well and properly, with one exception: I cannot get the database to start up on system boot. It tries with the brew-installed launchd item. But it fails for some reason. Once logged in to the computer, if I run that very same command as root, the database starts right up and runs no problem.

I've had similar problems in the past that were caused by the permissions on `/usr/local/var/mysql` but that does not appear to be the problem here.

So here's the specifics. This is the launchd item I'm using to start the server. It *is* running, I can see the database try to start up in its error log.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
            <string>homebrew.mxcl.mariadb</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                <string>/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
                <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
            </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
            <true/>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
            <string>/usr/local/var</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

So that tries to start up the database, but fails. But when I run that very same command in the terminal after boot, the database starts right up fine. But if I forget to do this, of course the world will explode or at least something bad will happen.

```
sudo /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
```

When the launchd plist tries to start up the server, the following is created in the server's error log:

```
210626 04:12:38 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2021-06-26  4:12:39 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.9-MariaDB) starting as process 468 ...
2021-06-26  4:12:39 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 256 (request: 32186)
2021-06-26  4:12:39 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 256  max_connections: 151 (was 151)  table_cache: 200 (was 2000)
2021-06-26  4:12:39 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2021-06-26  4:12:39 0 [ERROR] Aborting
210626 04:12:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Home-Server.local.pid ended
```

There are a few `warnings` but the only error is just a message `Aborting`. It doesn't say *WHY* it is Aborting. Is one of the Warnings causing a problem? If so, which one? And why does the server start up fine if I do it from the terminal? Surely the max connections count and the case sensitivity of the filesystem are the same.

I am at a loss.

Comment: Above it is the mention about running it as root. That’s the culprit. It shouldn’t be run as root

Comment: Isn't the way it works that you run mysqld_safe as root, and that launches the database as the proper user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! I'm not sure how or why it works, but if you add `sudo` to the command launchd runs, mariadb is able to start up normally! This doesn't make sense because these launchdeamons are *already* being run as root, so adding `sudo` shouldn't DO anything. Yet, it fixes it! Go figure.

```
...
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/sudo</string>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mariadbd-safe</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
    </array>
...
```